# Как перекрыть элемент в wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf

[image: Expander раскрывается над TextBox. Это затрудняет выбор элемента из списка]

`Expander` раскрывается над `TextBox`. Это затрудняет выбор элемента из списка. Т.е. когда курсор наведен на элемент списка, на него реагирует `TextBox` и выделить невозможно пока курсор в пересечении элемента экспандера и текстбокса. Как сделать так, чтобы `TextBox` был "неактивен" во время раскрытия экспандера?

Ниже код контрола c Экспандером и Главного окна

```xml
<Grid Background="#4D4D4D">
    <Border Grid.Column="0" BorderThickness="0,7.7,0,0" BorderBrush="{StaticResource ShadowTop}">
        <ListBoxItem x:Name="ListViewItemMenu" 
                     VerticalContentAlignment="Center" 
                     HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                     FontSize="16"
                     Content="{Binding Path=Header}"/>
    </Border>
    <Expander x:Name="ExpanderMenu" 
              Header="{Binding Path=Header}" 
              Background="{x:Null}"
              BorderThickness="0,7.7,0,0"
              Opacity="1">
        <ListView x:Name="ListViewMenu" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SubItems}" 
                  Foreground="White"
                  Opacity="1"
                  SelectionChanged="ListViewMenu_SelectionChanged">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"
                               Opacity="1"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Expander>
</Grid>
```

Фрагмент кода `MainWindow`. Контролы добавляются в стекпанели в codebehind

```xml
<Canvas x:Name="CanvasRight" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
    <!--панель меню-->
    <StackPanel Canvas.Top="0"  Canvas.ZIndex="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <StackPanel x:Name="menuPanel1" />
        <StackPanel x:Name="menuPanel2" />
        <StackPanel x:Name="menuPanel3" />
        <StackPanel x:Name="menuPanel4" />
    </StackPanel>
    <!--область страницы-->
    <StackPanel Margin="0" Canvas.Top="60" Canvas.ZIndex="2" x:Name="mainStackPanel" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBox IsReadOnly="True" Width="500">fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffeeeeeeeeeeeeeefefeferfergergvegergergerge</TextBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Canvas>
```

Comment: Покажите разметку

Comment: @Андрей NOP, добавил

Comment: Так уберите ZIndex с текстбокса. Точнее с панели, в которой он находится. И используйте `Grid` вместо `Canvas`.

Comment: @aepot, Спасибо, весь вечер просидел вчера )

Comment: По-хорошему вам нужно использовать штатное `Menu`, натянув на него нужные стили, или даже `ControlTemplate`. А коллекцию элементов грузить из `List` или `ObservableCollection`. Если кратко, то если вам понадобится динамически изменять состав главного меню, вы столкнетесь с трудностями, потому что у вас захардкожено 4 пункта меню. Познакомьтесь с `ItemsControl` и `ListBox`, посмотрите примеры, изучите, как делается `Binding` к коллекции с помощью `ItemsSource`. `Menu` - это тот же `ItemsControl`, только уже заточеный под нужды меню. Еще есть команды - искать `ICommand` и класс `RelayCommand`.

Comment: ...А чтобы сложность доработки проекта не возрастала в геометрической прогрессии при дальшейшей разработке - вам поможет шаблон проектирования MVVM. Без него писать вменяемые полноценные приложения в WPF - очень сложно.

Comment: @aepot. Спасибо за развернутые наставления и советы. Это не первый мой проект (и 2 с MVVM), просто давно не практиковался, а с экспандером впервые столкнулся (+ код взял с видеоурока по MaterialDesign. Там меню экспандится в левой части вертикально а мне уперлось сделать это сверху в горизонте).

Comment: Тут проблема с ZIndexom возникла. Изначально его нашел как способ сделать так, чтоб содержимое под экспандером не улетало вниз при раскрытии и в тонкости проставления этих индексов в справке не посвятили. Думал раз есть ZIndex1 значит должен быть и ZIndex2... Сейчас разобрался с этим и дальше все по уму сделаю.

Comment: Если уж хочется самому порисовать, то идея примерно такова `<Grid><Grid>здесь остальные контролы</Grid><Grid>здесь меню</Grid></Grid>`, то есть 2 следующих друг за другом грида, второй грид наложится на первый, и даже `ZIndex` не потребуется, `Canvas` тоже здесь мимо. Гриды [можно синхронизировать](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4664030/12888024) по высоте строк/ширине колонок.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@aepot в комментариях дал правильное решение. Нужно было убрать `Canvas.ZIndex` из `StackPanel`.

```xml
<StackPanel Margin="0" Canvas.Top="60" x:Name="mainStackPanel" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBox IsReadOnly="True" Width="500">fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffeeeeeeeeeeeeeefefeferfergergvegergergerge</TextBox>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Посиавьте галку ответу